# Is there a simple analytic method to solve for n in this equation?

Tags: exponential-function

$n\cdot2^n = r,\; r \in \mathbb{Q}, n \in \mathbb{R}$

I'm trying to solve for the input size of a $n\cdot \log_2 n$ algorithm, i.e. I started out with $n\cdot \log_2 n = 100$

Comment: Look up the Lambert W function. Heads up, the solution to $x log x = 100$ is almost certainly not an integer.

Comment: Ah..yes,  edited that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$n = \dfrac{W(r \ln(2))}{\ln(2)}$$
where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)